# How to remove movieclips that contains specific word in instance name

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5.5

I have a situation where i am trying to remove certain movie clips that do not have any instance name given to  them ,  they are created dynamically , i can find the movieclips by using the below code :

```
for (var i:uint = 0; i <worldc1.numChildren; i++){

  trace (worldc1.getChildAt(i).name );

}
```

however as i know that some default instance name is assigned to each movie clip , that starts with word "`instance`" ...

How can i remove all such movie clips  that have  word "`instance`" in  their name ...

Or best how i can remove a movieclips that has no instance name assigned to it and are dynamically created ....

I tried using  the contains but its not working .....

Thanks in advance ...

Regards

Comment: Try `worldc1.getChildAt(i).name.indexOf("instance")<0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this function:

```
removeClipsWithNameContaining(worldc1, "instance");


function removeClipsWithNameContaining(target:DisplayObjectContainer, str:String):void {

    var clips:Array = [];

    for (var i:uint = 0; i < target.numChildren; i++){
        if(target.getChildAt(i).name.indexOf(str) != -1) clips.push(target.getChildAt(i));
    }

    var c:int = clips.length;       
    while(--c > -1) target.removeChild(clips.pop());

}
```

Comment: wow - thanks a lot for even writing the function it saved me, i owe you a beer friend @cherniv - thanks for pointing in the right direction ....